# TCP segment length with TLS is almost 8KB

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, openssl

I'm sniffing a connection using TLS with OpenSSL. Both application running in the same node and connecting through the local interface. Even though, the max size allowed by TLS Record Protocol is 16KB and the MSS negotiated by TCP is ~64KB, I'm seeing TLS application protocol messages being sent from one node to the other as 2 TCP messages of 8221-Byte payloads (TCP payload).
Note this is a connection between two applications in the same nodeand TCP's MSS=65495.

Why can't I see one TCP message of ~16KB instead of two TCP messages of ~8KB?

Comment: Because the application is only providing 8k at a time to TLS.

Comment: @EJP, do you think it's the application providing 8KB of data to OpenSSL with WRITE_ssl or is it OpenSSL that processes 8KB each time and passes 8KB to the socket?

Comment: I believe what I said. That's why I said it.

Comment: @rodolk - It could be slow start algorithm or it could be a hard coded BIO limit. Or, it could be the application as EJP stated. In either case, checkout [Optimizing NGINX TLS Time To First Byte (TTTFB)](http://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/) for some useful hints when contemplating the behavior. You might also want to research *"long fat pipe"* to see if it helps explain some of the behavior you are observing. See, for example, [Long Fat Pipes: TCP WSCALE, TCP SACK and Time Stamp Options](http://mccltd.net/blog/?p=1864).